# Последнему из могикан() А. Звягинцеву

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно написать шутливое посвящение: *Последнему из могикан() А. Звягинцеву*? Нужно ли брать в кавычки *Последнему из могикан*? Нужна ли запятая на месте скобок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставшее фразеологизмом определение не берут в кавычки и, как и любое определение, от определяемого не отделяют никак. Однако, для пущей пафосности, можно поставить тире. Можно на этом месте представить и точку, но в таком случае лучше имя дать полностью, чтобы А не выглядела окружённой точками.

Comment: "Для пущей пафосности" - или в двух запятых, или убрать после "однако". )))

Comment: Согласен, надо было...